# Escaping & (ampersand) in SOQL

Tags: php, salesforce, soql

I have this piece of code to search for data on Salesforce:

Code:

```
$campaign_name = 'A & B Campaign';  
$search = 'FIND {'.$campaign_name.'} IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING CAMPAIGN(ID)';
$searchResult = $mySforceConnection->search($search);
var_dump('$searchResult: ' . print_r($searchResult, true));
```

Error:

```
mismatched character '&' expecting '}'
```

I tried to use `preg_replace`, `htmlentities`, I keep getting the same error, what can I do to be able to search for strings containing `&`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a slash, like that: `FIND {A \& B}` (that's a valid SOSL search by the way ;))

Scroll to bottom of https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_examples.htm for more info.

No idea if there's a built-in php function that would do this for you. Worst case create your own utility function with `str_replace`, `preg_replace` etc.

Comment: Thanks @eyescream!