# How to escape &?

Tags: c#, salesforce, soql

I am trying to run following query through Saleforce's REST client in my C# application,

```
Select Id, Name, Family FROM Product2 Where Name IN ('Connectivity - HMS','Database & Application Services', ....)
```

but getting following error:

```
('Connectivity - HMS','Database 
                              ^
```

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:83 line 1:83 mismatched character '< EOF >'
>   expecting '''

It works fine if I remove names with & in them.

I am using ForceClient to run the query:

```
var client = new ForceClient(_instanceUrl, _accessToken, _apiVersion);
Task<QueryResult<dynamic>> queryResult = client.QueryAsync<dynamic>(query);
queryResult.Wait();
```

I have tried many different things to replace & like `Regex.Replace, &amp;, \\&` but nothing worked.

The same query is working perfectly in Developer Console.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are passing this query in to the REST server? I suspect you may need to HtmlEncode the query to be valid for passing to a REST server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping & (ampersand) in SOQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541670/escaping-ampersand-in-soql)

Comment: I have updated my with details of how I am running the query.
I have tried to escape using \\ & but it didnt work either

Comment: I could image that this is a similar bug like mentioned here:https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/issues/93
So just try the similar replacing like in the link just replace your '&'
query.Replace("+", "%26");

Comment: Sorry I mean of course: query.Replace("&", "%26");

Comment: Uri.EscapeDataString(value) fixed the issue. Please add your answer and I will select it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send the `&` character over a HTTP link to a server as part of the parameter value eg: `'Database & Application Services'` it will need to be encoded.

In this case, as the call to the server is via a REST web service and REST services use the URL and the query string you should encode the query string to make sure all non-control characters that are part of the parameters are properly encoded.

Use one of the three methods shown below depending on your preferences or circumstances:

```
System.Uri.EscapeDataString
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode
System.Web.Mvc.Url.Encode
```

If you are on the server side needing to decode what people have sent, then use:

```
Systen.Uri.UnescapeDataString
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

Finally, if you not inside of a Web based project, there is this alternative:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode
```